# text from With statement to geometry and geography

Tags: postgresql, postgis

```
WITH values(location, userid) as (
VALUES (st_geomfromewkt('0101000000000000C04141464000000000FE174440'),5))

SELECT st_distance(p.location,(SELECT location FROM values where v.userid = "blacklisterId")::geometry)
FROM values as v,live.partners as p
Inner JOIN backend.cars c ON (c."userId" = p."partnerId" AND c.active = true)
Inner JOIN backend."carCompatibleTariffs" cCT ON c."carId" = cCT."carId" and  1 = cCT."tariffId" AND cCT.active = true
LEFT JOIN backend."userBlacklist" bl on 5 = bl."blacklisterId" AND p."partnerId" = bl."blacklistedId"
WHERE bl."blacklistedId" ISNULL
--AND st_dwithin(p.location::geography,(SELECT FROM values where v.userid = "blacklisterId")::geography,1500)
--ORDER BY st_distance(p.location,(SELECT location FROM values where v.userid = "blacklisterId")::geometry) ASC;
```

How to take text values table as geometry or geography,I tried to make it with ST_GeographyFromText,ST_GeogmetryFromText and with st_makepoint((Select st_x),(Select st_y)) but it always return null,how can I solve this ?

Comment: You mean you want to convert a text, e.g. wkt, to geometry?

Comment: yes,text is inserted from nodejs

Comment: Alright. In which format is your text delivered? WKT, GeoJSON, EWKT,..?

Comment: It's simple text comes from another db in witch format is geometry,I want to use location data from one db in another

Comment: Your example already seems to have a valid geometry. What does this command give you?
`SELECT ST_AsText('0101000000000000C04141464000000000FE174440');`

Comment: VALUES ('0101000000000000C04141464000000000FE174440',5),

st_distance(p.location,ST_AsText((SELECT location FROM values where v.userid = "blacklisterId"))::geometry) and st_dwithin(p.location::geography,st_astext((SELECT location FROM values where v.userid = "blacklisterId"))::geography,1500) always return null

Comment: I wouldn't use `values` as a CTE name, *at least* to avoid confusion. (and you should use JOIN syntax, and probably NOT EXISTS(), too)

Comment: @Grigor I see no error with the geometries in the CTE. Are you sure that the joins are being fulfilled?

Comment: Yes,for example this returns not null values
      SELECT p."partnerId",p.location,p.rate,st_distance(p.location,'0101000000000000200A45464000000000D7174440'::geometry)
                                                     FROM live.partners as p

Comment: `(SELECT location FROM values where v.userid = "blacklisterId")::geometry)` This scalar subquery refers to the `v.` alias from an outer scope. I don't think this is wanted.

Comment: would you try changing this subquery `SELECT location FROM values where v.userid = "blacklisterId"` to `SELECT location FROM values where v.userid = 'blacklisterId'`?

Comment: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "blacklisterId"

Comment: `v.userid = "blacklisterId"` userid has INTEGER value 5 in the values(...)

Comment: Thanks,5 is only for testing

Comment: @Grigor I'm positive that the problem is not related to the CTE/geometries. Since we do not know the structure and content of the other tables, it would be helpful if you could add them to your question. Preferably in a fiddle (not mandatory). Add the create table statements and some sample data.

Comment: create table partners(live.partners)
   (
  "partnerId"  integer                      not null
    constraint partners_pkey
    primary key,
  location    geometry,
); 
blacklist is simple connection table integers only
values come from table order( location geometry)

Comment: @Grigor add this info + sample data to the question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be somewhere else. Your geometry seems to be valid:

```
WITH values(location, userid) AS 
(VALUES ('0101000000000000C04141464000000000FE174440',5),
        ('0101000000000000200A45464000000000D7174440',16))
SELECT ST_Distance(location::GEOMETRY,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(44 45)')) FROM values;

   st_distance    
------------------
 4.83948955585514
 4.84387473202619
(2 Zeilen)
```

Here a few examples on different types of geometry literals:

[`ST_GeomFromText`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html)

```
db=# SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)');
              st_geomfromtext               
--------------------------------------------
 0101000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
(1 Zeile)
```

[`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html):

```
db=# SELECT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,2]}');
             st_geomfromgeojson             
--------------------------------------------
 0101000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
(1 Zeile)
```

[`ST_GeomFromEWKT`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromEWKT.html):

```
db=# SELECT ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4269;POINT(1 2)');
                  st_geomfromewkt                   
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020AD100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
(1 Zeile)
```

[`ST_GeomFromGML`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGML.html):

```
db=# SELECT ST_GeomFromGML('<gml:Point><gml:coordinates>1,2</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>');
               st_geomfromgml               
--------------------------------------------
 0101000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
(1 Zeile)
```

[`ST_GeomFromKML`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromKML.html):

```
db=# SELECT ST_GeomFromKML('<Point><coordinates>1,2</coordinates></Point>');
                   st_geomfromkml                   
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
(1 Zeile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This *could* have been your intention:

---

```
WITH vvv(location, userid) as (
    VALUES (st_geomfromewkt('0101000000000000C04141464000000000FE174440'),5)
    )
SELECT st_distance(p.location, v.location::geometry) AS THE_DISTANCE
FROM vvv as v
JOIN live.partners as p
    ON p."partnerId" = v.userid
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM backend.cars c
    JOIN backend."carCompatibleTariffs" cCT
            ON c."carId" = cCT."carId"
            AND cCT."tariffId" = 1 AND cCT.active = true
    WHERE c."userId" = p."partnerId"
    AND c.active = true
    )
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM backend."userBlacklist" bl
    WHERE p."partnerId" = bl."blacklistedId"
    AND 5 = bl."blacklisterId"
    )
    ;
```